# rails 4 nested resource unable to get form_for to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, form-for, nested-form-for

Im unable to get my form_for to work for a nested resource and it's driving crazy.

**routes:**

```
namespace :teacher do
    resources :lessons do
      resources :questions
      resources :invites
      resources :responses
    end
end
```

**app/views/teacher/questions/_form.html.haml:**

```
= simple_form_for [:teacher, @question], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal form-lineup' } do |f|

  ..
```

index, show, destroy actions all work correctly.
Only Edit action fails when calling :

```
teachers/1/questions/1/edit
```

Throws:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teacher/questions", :teacher_id=>#<Teacher::Question id: 1, teacher_id: 5, user_id: nil, name: "asdf", email: "dsafsd", expire_at: "2013-12-23 19:36:00", created_at: "2013-12-23 19:36:25", updated_at: "2013-12-23 19:36:25">, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on the route definition you provided, the edit path for questions should be `teacher/lessons/1/questions/1/edit` and not `teachers/1/questions/1/edit`.

You could refer to the guides for how to use namespaces in routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Your form should probably look like this:

```
= simple_form_for [:teacher, @lesson, @question], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal form-lineup' } do |f|
```

Or try:

```
= simple_form_for @question, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal form-lineup' }, url: edit_teacher_lesson_question_path(@lesson, @question), method: :put do |f|
```

If you want to produce this path `teachers/1/questions/1/edit`, you need to define the route this way:

```
resources :teachers do
  resources :questions
end
```

Comment: These docs also state multiple /magazines/:magazine_id/ads exactly what I have implemented at this moment. The problem seems to be the form_for line in my _form the routing itself goes okay ( it shows the edit form when i remove this form_for tag from it) :(

Comment: Ok I see your point thanks for the writeup. What would the routes look like in that case? namespace :teacher do resource :teacher ?

Comment: If you want to produce this path `teachers/1/questions/1/edit`, you need to define the route this way:
`resources :teachers do
  resources :questions
end`